# CSS: multi column layout rips text apart in Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm having issues with Safari (9.0.1) and displaying text over multiple columns: it just rips lines horizontally (!) apart so that the ascenders remain in the previous (bottom) line and the rest of the letters is displayed at the top of the new column (see attached screenshot). This behaviour renders the columns feature basically useless. At the same time Firefox (42.0) and Chrome (47.0.2526.80) are totally fine with the CSS.

Is that a Safari-specific issue, did I just do something wrong or is my system messed up?

And (in addition): is it normal for Webkit-browser to calculate differently? On a 1280px wide display, Firefox displays up to 4 columns (4x (300px + 2x 10px)) whereas the Webkit browsers stick to 3 columns (when reducing column-width to 296px, they do display 4 columns, even though that just sums up to 1264px).

**Edit**: I've added another screenshot of the whole text spread over different columns with added markers of the problem.

```css
html {
 overflow: display;
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}

.content {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 padding: 0 10px;
 -moz-column-width: 300px;
 -webkit-column-width: 300px;
 column-width: 300px;
 -moz-column-gap: 20px;
 -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
 column-gap: 20px;
 column-fill: balance;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Headline Headline</h1>
    <h2>Er hörte leise Schritte hinter sich. Das bedeutete nichts Gutes. Wer würde ihm schon folgen, spät in der Nacht und dazu noch in dieser engen Gasse mitten im übel beleumundeten Hafenviertel? Gerade jetzt, wo er das Ding seines Lebens gedreht hatte und mit der Beute verschwinden wollte!</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis tempor rutrum. Sed eu odio rhoncus, molestie sapien eget, hendrerit elit. Aliquam at tellus a dui lacinia euismod a et dolor. Integer tempor leo ac quam sodales, sit amet sollicitudin risus facilisis. Donec sed purus non sapien consequat egestas. Curabitur laoreet aliquam leo, id vestibulum dui ornare sed. Nullam lectus felis, malesuada ac congue quis, suscipit vel ante. Mauris id tristique dui, quis malesuada enim. Curabitur neque quam, pellentesque ut libero sed, aliquam malesuada ligula.</p>
 <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam a dapibus mi, vel adipiscing lacus. Vivamus adipiscing urna eget ligula gravida, nec ultrices lorem tincidunt. Pellentesque arcu nulla, viverra ut dui et, fermentum gravida justo. Nullam eget ligula quis ligula convallis fringilla et vitae ligula. Sed ornare metus dictum, consectetur urna in, iaculis magna. Ut purus nibh, pretium id placerat sit amet, interdum ornare eros. Etiam ac viverra lectus, in gravida orci. Phasellus aliquam sapien vitae porttitor volutpat.</p>
 <p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles. Ma quande lingues coalesce, li grammatica del resultant lingue es plu simplic e regulari quam ti del coalescent lingues. Li nov lingua franca va esser plu simplic e regulari quam li existent Europan lingues. It va esser tam simplic quam Occidental in fact, it va esser Occidental. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles.</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis tempor rutrum. Sed eu odio rhoncus, molestie sapien eget, hendrerit elit. Aliquam at tellus a dui lacinia euismod a et dolor. Integer tempor leo ac quam sodales, sit amet sollicitudin risus facilisis. Donec sed purus non sapien consequat egestas. Curabitur laoreet aliquam leo, id vestibulum dui ornare sed. Nullam lectus felis, malesuada ac congue quis, suscipit vel ante. Mauris id tristique dui, quis malesuada enim. Curabitur neque quam, pellentesque ut libero sed, aliquam malesuada ligula.</p>
 <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam a dapibus mi, vel adipiscing lacus. Vivamus adipiscing urna eget ligula gravida, nec ultrices lorem tincidunt. Pellentesque arcu nulla, viverra ut dui et, fermentum gravida justo. Nullam eget ligula quis ligula convallis fringilla et vitae ligula. Sed ornare metus dictum, consectetur urna in, iaculis magna. Ut purus nibh, pretium id placerat sit amet, interdum ornare eros. Etiam ac viverra lectus, in gravida orci. Phasellus aliquam sapien vitae porttitor volutpat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TryWB.png)

[Whole Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLdBv.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by it rips in the screenshot?

Comment: second column, first line: there are just some parts of the actual text. The rest of it sits at the bottom of the previous column. It tears the line horizontally apart. When resizing the window at some points it suddenly works fine and after a few pixels it tears it apart again.